# Could I use Infura to get the token details?

Tags: tokens, infura, explorer-api

I went through https://infura.io/docs but not sure if Infura could allow me to read token details like owner, token Id, etc. I also googled on how to read token using Infura but to no avail.

Has anyone tried it?

Answer (score 1):

Here's a demo that lets you pull NFT data programmatically from the blockchain:

https://github.com/cryptogoth/demo-erc721

for example, a few Devcon5 tickets are sold as NFTs
https://etherscan.io/token/0x22cc8b3666e926bcbf58cb726143b2b044c80a0c?a=34410171212740518240382548201030436272862311489479305301712148182074228170203

Using the demo, you can call any of the methods in the ERC721 ABI at
http://erc721.org

In particular, calling `ownerOf` for the token ID above gives:

```
NFT Owner is {"0":"0x66040374e443ae3e25afef08a781c4c2d175f43c"}
```

There is a manual step of creating / adding an empty Ethereum account,
which you can then use to call mutator methods that cost gas.
I'm working on automating this step from the command-line demo as well.
Hope it helps, questions and feedback welcome.

Comment: I dont mind, but the API doesn't allow me to view NFT token details.

Comment: @vocotipex you're correct, Etherscan is just ERC20. I changed my answer to include a demo for ERC721 using the Democracy framework. Let me know if you have problems using it.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
const Web3 = require("web3");

async function run() {
    const web3 = new Web3("https://mainnet.infura.io/v3/" + YOUR_INFURA_PROJECT_ID);
    const contract = new web3.eth.Contract(YOUR_CONTRACT_ABI, YOUR_CONTRACT_ADDRESS);
    const retVal = await contract.methods.somePureOrViewFunction(arg1, arg2).call();
    const varVal = await contract.methods.somePublicVariable().call();
}

run();
```

Comment: I'll try this and will let you know the outcome.